# HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>"

Tags: javascript, c#, html, internet-explorer, doctype

Good day,

I am working on a c# web application, everything is working until I add in a normal JavaScript.

The html code is something as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="headContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head> 
<body>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="title" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="bodyContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<!-- some code here -->
</body>
```

The `JScript.js` is the JavaScript that put in.

The JavaScript code is something as follow:

```
function getCookie(catId) {
  var ebRand = Math.random() + '';
ebRand = ebRand * 1000000; 

document.write('<scr' + 'ipt src="HTTP://bs.serving-sys.com/Serving/ActivityServer.bs?cn=as&amp;ActivityID=553971&amp;rnd=' + ebRand + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
}
```

This JavaScript function will be trigger when a link button is click.

I hit error in IE but Chrome and Mozilla is working fine.

My error in IE console is 
`HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>".`

After search in Google, I try to put in

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

as new `DOCTYPE`, but it not working also.

and I have try put

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

inside `<head></head>`

But I still get the same error in IE also.

Is is problem in `ContentPlaceHolder`?

Other than that, I have go to W3C Markup Validation Service to do some validation of the address :

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=HTTP%3A%2F%2Fbs.serving-sys.com%2FServing%2FActivityServer.bs%3Fcn%3Das%26amp%3BActivityID%3D553971%26amp%3Brnd%3D20079.082210606393&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

And go to http://validator.w3.org/check to put in `<script src="HTTP://bs.serving-sys.com/Serving/ActivityServer.bs?cn=as&amp;ActivityID=553971&amp;rnd=20079.082210606393"></script>`
as well.

But not understand what is the validation result means.

[image: What I get from IE script console]
Kindly advise.

Comment: which IE version are you getting that error in?  You can also try an html validator: http://validator.w3.org/.

Comment: IE 10. What to check at the website?

Comment: Load your page, view page source, copy the source and paste it into the direct input tab and hit check.  It'll try to validate your html structure and etc.

Comment: Hi Benny Lin, when I view page source, I just see `<script src="HTTP://bs.serving-sys.com/Serving/ActivityServer.bs?cn=as&amp;ActivityID=553971&amp;rnd=20079.082210606393"></script>`

So, when I copy over, validation get error. What does this means?

Comment: It means that calling document.write() after the initial page load blew the original document away. Don't know what ActivityServer.bs is supposed to do, so can't tell it that was supposed to happen or not.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  View page source should show the html and not your doc write item.  Try to remove the <script src="scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script> line and reload the page and check page source again.

Answer (score 1):

IE issues a *warning* about `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`, because such a string is [not a valid doctype according to HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype). The warning as such has no impact on anything. It’s just part of HTML5 evangelism.

After you changed it to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`, the issue was removed. But you probably saw the results of using some cached copy that has a wrong doctype. Testing with a fresh file (with a new name) should fix this issue.

Of course, the code as such does not validate, since the ASP tags are taken literally and interpreted as `body` content, but that’s a different issue.

The practical move is to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` as suggested. If you wish to still validate against the XHTML 1.0 specification for example, you can do this using the validator’s user interface to override the doctype.

But it’s not a big issue; you can just as well simply ignore the warning. If you have some *functional* errors, they are caused by something else and should be asked separately, with sufficient data provided.

Comment: Hi Jukka, I already clear cache, delete history, but still get the same error. In my page source, I still can see my `DOCTYPE` already change to `Strict`. However, I am still getting the same error when I `OnClick` (in master page(site.master)). Whole page will bank when hit this error. Is this anything wrong with the `ContentPlaceHolder` ? My html code in my question is on master page, whish is `Site.master`, but the error I get in on my `home.aspx` page, which is as follow :

HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>". 
Home.aspx, line 1 character 1

Comment: @PanadolChong, if the message appears when you click on something, then it is essential what code is executed. You need to present *actual* HTML and JavaScript code needed to reproduce the issue, if it is relevant to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Sorry not understand what you means. You want me to provide the full source code? or?

Comment: You need to provide code that actually reproduces the issue, preferably a minimal case (shortest and simplest code that still produces the problem).

Comment: just update my code on the JavaScript part. The html code is there. Kindly advise.

Comment: Sorry, but there is still no testable case. It is not at all clear what you are asking; the question is far too vague and does not focus to a demonstrable problem. It is unclear why you are worried about IE’s warning. And you have submitted a piece of JavaScript code to HTML validator; the response means simply that no HTML was submitted.

Comment: Maybe can just take the JavaScript function as a test case. Because, maybe IE's warning is not a big Issue, but this warning cause the page display blank. User cant see anything after trigger the function.